# pre_get_comments to restrict current users view of edit-comment.php to their comments

Tags: functions

Here is what I have to far that is not working:

```
function comments_for_current_author($query) {
    global $pagenow;
  
    if( 'edit-comments.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;
  
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
        
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author', $user_ID );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_comments', 'comments_for_current_author');
```